# Disk Utility error

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

After creating new partition both NTFS and FAT utilizing disk utility I am getting the "Running operation 2 of 3: Erase “files”…" -> "Operation failed…" error.

Nevertheless, partitions are created and visible in Finder.

Is it safe to use them despite error during creation?

**Error's screenshot:**

[image: Error screenshot]

[image]

**diskutil list:**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         106.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨files⁩                   836.9 GB   disk0s6
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨Windows⁩                 81.0 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +106.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨macos⁩                   24.0 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 24.0 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 292.4 MB   disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                611.0 MB   disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨macos - Data⁩            76.1 GB    disk1s5
```